# table background image is not displaying in outlook

Tags: marketing-cloud, email-template, html

I have a HTML email in sales force marketing cloud.

The email consist of a table with background image. the email looks good in the preview but once send the table - background image is not displaying in outlook but the email is rendering fine in gmail.
the html code is as below

```
<table align="left" background="http://image.email.resmed.com.au/lib/fe8f13727c64037e71/m/1/fa3cd486-d5b8-4b85-872c-29a682e87fe5.jpg" valign="top" width="100%">
<tr>
  <td style="padding:30px 30px 30px 30px">
      <table align="left" style="background-color:rgba(255,255, 255, 1);padding:30px 30px 30px 30px" valign="top" width="50%">
       <tr>
         <td style="color: rgb(0, 134, 197);font-family:Arial;"> ACTIVATE NOW TO EARN</td>
       </tr>
      </table>
  </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Kindly help!

New HTML after edits based on answer below: (still having issues)

```
<table align="left" valign="top" width="600" background="image.email.resmed.com.au/lib/fe8f13727c64037e71‌​/m/1/…; 
  <!--[if gte mso 9]> <v:rect style="width:600px;height:auto" strokecolor="none">
    <v:fill type="tile" src="image.email.resmed.com.au/lib/fe8f13727c64037e71/m/1/…; />
    </v:fill>
  </v:rect>
  <v:shape id="NameHere" style="position:absolute;width:600x;height:auto">
<![endif]-->
  <tr>
   <td style="padding:30px 30px 30px 30px">
      <table align="left" style="background-color:rgba(255,255, 255, 1);padding:30px 30px 30px 30px" valign="top" width="50%">
       <tr>
         <td style="color: rgb(0, 134, 197);font-family:Arial;">ACTIVATE NOW TO EARN</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
<!--[if gte mso 9]>
</v:shape>
<![endif]-->
</table>
```

Thanks
Suraksha G B

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you have not posted your code, I do not know for sure, but this is likely due to [Outlook not supporting bgimage or background image CSS](https://emailmonks.com/blog/email-marketing/background-images-emails/).

> The prime culprit seems to be Outlook 07/10/13, which does not support either table background email images or background-image styles.

To combat this, you will need to use a [microsoft language called VML (Vector Markup Language)](https://www.emailonacid.com/blog/article/email-development/emailology_vector_markup_language_and_backgrounds)

The easiest way to accomplish this is by using an awesome tool [Stig](https://www.campaignmonitor.com/company/#stigm) has created: https://backgrounds.cm/

This will help you with setting up a 'bulletproof background' for Outlook and more.

Sample of the code:

```
<td background="https://i.imgur.com/YJOX1PC.png" bgcolor="#7bceeb" width="120" height="92" valign="top">
  <!--[if gte mso 9]>
    <v:rect xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" fill="true" stroke="false" style="width:120px;height:92px;">
      <v:fill type="tile" src="https://i.imgur.com/YJOX1PC.png" color="#7bceeb" />
       <v:textbox inset="0,0,0,0">
  <![endif]-->
  <div>
         <!-- YOUR CONTENT -->
  </div>
  <!--[if gte mso 9]>
    </v:textbox>
  </v:rect>
  <![endif]-->
</td>
```

---

**EDIT**

Based on your new code, I believe what you are trying to do is the below:

```
<table align="left" valign="top" width="600">
<tr>
  <td style="padding:30px 30px 30px 30px">
      <table align="left" style="background-color:rgba(255,255, 255, 1);padding:30px 30px 30px 30px" valign="top" width="50%">
       <tr>
         <td background="http://image.email.resmed.com.au/lib/fe8f13727c64037e71/m/1/fa3cd486-d5b8-4b85-872c-29a682e87fe5.jpg" width="50%" valign="top" style="rgb(0, 134, 197); font-family:Arial;">
  <!--[if gte mso 9]>
    <v:rect xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" fill="true" stroke="false" style="width:{{YourWidth}}; height:{{YourHeight}};">
      <v:fill type="tile" src="http://image.email.resmed.com.au/lib/fe8f13727c64037e71/m/1/fa3cd486-d5b8-4b85-872c-29a682e87fe5.jpg" color="#7bceeb" />
       <v:textbox inset="0,0,0,0">
  <![endif]-->
ACTIVATE NOW TO EARN
  <!--[if gte mso 9]>
    </v:textbox>
  </v:rect>
  <![endif]-->
</td>
       </tr>
      </table>
  </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

You would just need to add the width/height in defined px into the VML for Outlook to render.

Comment: here is my html email code.

<table align="left" background="http://image.email.resmed.com.au/lib/fe8f13727c64037e71/m/1/fa3cd486-d5b8-4b85-872c-29a682e87fe5.jpg" valign="top" width="100%">
 
  <tr>
   <td style="padding:30px 30px 30px 30px">
    <table align="left" style="background-color:rgba(255,255, 255, 1);padding:30px 30px 30px 30px" valign="top" width="50%">
     
      <tr>
       <td style="color: rgb(0, 134, 197);font-family:Arial;">
        ACTIVATE NOW TO EARN</td></tr></table>
       </td></tr></table>

Comment: i used the way which is suggested but the images still not rendering fine.
kindly help!

Comment: can you provide more details into what you mean by 'not rendering fine'.  Have you checked image blocking settings on Outlook?

Comment: i have tried with changing the outlook setting for automatic download but still the background image given for the table tag is not displaying in the email.
kindly help

Comment: can you provide the code you are now using (after utilizing the above solution)? You can just edit your question to include the new code in it.

Comment: <table align="left"  valign="top" width="600" background="http://image.email.resmed.com.au/lib/fe8f13727c64037e71/m/1/fa3cd486-d5b8-4b85-872c-29a682e87fe5.jpg">
  <!--[if gte mso 9]>
       <v:rect style="width:600px;height:auto" strokecolor="none">
         <v:fill type="tile"  src="http://image.email.resmed.com.au/lib/fe8f13727c64037e71/m/1/fa3cd486-d5b8-4b85-872c-29a682e87fe5.jpg" /></v:fill>
       </v:rect>
       <v:shape id="NameHere" style="position:absolute;width:600x;height:auto">
       <![endif]-->

Comment: <tr>
   <td  style="padding:30px 30px 30px 30px">
  
    <table align="left" style="background-color:rgba(255,255, 255, 1);padding:30px 30px 30px 30px" valign="top" width="50%">
     
      <tr>
       <td style="color: rgb(0, 134, 197);font-family:Arial;">
        ACTIVATE NOW TO EARN</td></tr></table>
  
  </td></tr>
   <!--[if gte mso 9]>
       </v:shape>
       <![endif]-->
  </table>

Comment: The above is the code which i used based on the suggestion posted here, but when i receive the email in my inbox the image background image is not displaying. Kindly help